# Array de objetos vacios para registro de usuarios en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola cómo va? Yo estoy iniciando recién en `front end developer`, estoy aprendiendo `javascript` y estoy trabado en la creación de un `array` de objetos vacío donde ahí se guardaran los datos de los usuarios que se registren y me salta error en el `console.log` para ver como queda, al principio era en los `select` del `form` vinculados, los comenté para ver de donde mas venía el error y ahora encontré que no toma los valores del registro por fuera del evento. paso primero `html` y despues el `js`.

HTML:

```
<h2 id="registrate">Registrate</h2>
<div class="container-fluid formRegistro">
    <div class="container cont-formL">
        <form class="formrow">
            <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="nombre">

            <label for="Apellido">Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" name="Apellido" id="apellido">


            <label for="cod-area">Codigo de area</label>
            <input type="number" name="cod-area" id="codArea">

            <label for="celular">Telefono celular</label>
            <input type="tel" name="celular" id="celular">

            <label for="genero">Género</label>
            <select class="form-select" name="genero" id="genero">
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-formR">
        <form class="formrow">
            <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">

            <label for="Cuil-Cuit">Cuil/Cuit</label>
            <input type="text" name="Cuil-Cuit" id="cuilCuit">

            <label for="fecha-nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
            <input type="date" name="fecha-nacimiento" id="fechaNacimiento">

            <label for="edad">Edad</label>
            <input type="number" name="edad" id="edad">

            <label for="provincia">Provincia</label>
            <select type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia">
                <option value="Seleccione">-Seleccione una provincia-</option>
                <option value="Buenos Aires">Buenos Aires</option>
                <option value="Catamarca">Catamarca</option>
                <option value="Chaco">Chaco</option>
                <option value="Chubut">Chubut</option>
            </select>

            <div class="btnForm">
                <button type="button" class="btn btnTop btn-warning" id="btnregistro">Registrarme</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btnBottom btn-warning">Borrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Javascritp:

```
let btnregistro = document.getElementById( "btnregistro" )

btnregistro.addEventListener( "click", function ( loguin ) {
   loguin.preventDefault();
   let nombre = document.getElementById( "nombre" ).value;
   let apellido = document.getElementById( "apellido" ).value;
   let codArea = document.getElementById( "codArea" ).value;
   let celular = document.getElementById( "celular" ).value;
   let generoX = document.getElementById( "genero" ).value;
   let email = document.getElementById( "email" ).value;
   let cuilCuit = document.getElementById( "cuilCuit" ).value;
   let fechaNacimiento = document.getElementById( "fechaNacimiento" ).value;
   let edad = document.getElementById( "edad" ).value;
   let provinciaX = document.getElementById( "provincia" ).value

   class Usuario {

      constructor( nombre, apellido, codArea, celular, generoX, email, cuilCuit, fechaNacimiento, edad, provinciaX ) {
         this.nombre = nombre
         this.apellido = apellido
         this.codArea = codArea
         this.celular = celular
         this.generoX = generoX
         this.email = email
         this.cuilCuit = cuilCuit
         this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento
         this.edad = edad
         this.provinciaX = provinciaX
      }
   }

   let usuarioX = new Usuario( nombre, apellido, codArea, celular, generoX, email, cuilCuit,
           fechaNacimiento, edad, provinciaX );
   localStorage.setItem( "usuarioX", JSON.stringify( usuarioX ) );
} )

console.log( localStorage.getItem( "usuarioX" ) );
```

Comment: Hola Martin, si nunca antes guardaste algo en el `localStorage` es lógico que no haya nada y que devuelva `null`. El `console.log` deberías hacerlo después de crear un `usuarioX`

Comment: Buen día, ¿Cuál sería el error en cuestión?...

Answer (score 0):

para que puedas ver el resultado por consola debes colocar el `console.log` dentro de la función, y no fuera. Ya que de la estas llamado a `usuarioX` antes de instanciarlo, como te ha comentado Marcos.

Consejo: Mira de no sobrecargar tanto la función, será un poco más legible, ejemplo:

```javascript
const btnregistro = document.getElementById("btnregistro")

class Usuario {
    constructor(usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario
    }
}

const saveLocalStorage = (usuario) => {
    localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(usuario));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
}

btnregistro.addEventListener("click", function (loguin) {

    loguin.preventDefault();

    let usuario = {}
    usuario.nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value
    usuario.apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value
    usuario.codArea = document.getElementById("codArea").value
    usuario.genero = document.getElementById("genero").value
    usuario.email = document.getElementById("email").value
    usuario.cuilCuit = document.getElementById("cuilCuit").value
    usuario.fechaNacinamiento = document.getElementById("fechaNacimiento").value
    usuario.edad = document.getElementById("edad").value
    usuario.provincia = document.getElementById("provincia").value

    usuario = new Usuario(usuario);
    saveLocalStorage(usuario);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema con tu código, es que está cargando el JS antes del html, con solo evitar esto, funciona bien (también quité la clase del interior de la función).

```js
  // envolvemos el código en una función que pueda ser llamada en el momento necesario
function iniciar() {

   let btnregistro = document.getElementById( "btnregistro" );

   btnregistro.addEventListener( "click", function( loguin ) {
      loguin.preventDefault();
      let nombre = document.getElementById( "nombre" ).value;
      let apellido = document.getElementById( "apellido" ).value;
      let codArea = document.getElementById( "codArea" ).value;
      let celular = document.getElementById( "celular" ).value;
      let generoX = document.getElementById( "genero" ).value;
      let email = document.getElementById( "email" ).value;
      let cuilCuit = document.getElementById( "cuilCuit" ).value;
      let fechaNacimiento = document.getElementById( "fechaNacimiento" ).value;
      let edad = document.getElementById( "edad" ).value;
      let provinciaX = document.getElementById( "provincia" ).value;

      let usuarioX = new Usuario( nombre, apellido, codArea, celular, generoX, 
                            email, cuilCuit, fechaNacimiento, edad, provinciaX );
      localStorage.setItem( "usuarioX", JSON.stringify( usuarioX ));

      console.log( localStorage.getItem( "usuarioX" ));
   });
}

class Usuario {

   constructor( nombre, apellido, codArea, celular, generoX, 
                  email, cuilCuit, fechaNacimiento, edad, provinciaX ) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.apellido = apellido;
      this.codArea = codArea;
      this.celular = celular;
      this.generoX = generoX;
      this.email = email;
      this.cuilCuit = cuilCuit;
      this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
      this.edad = edad;
      this.provinciaX = provinciaX;
   }
}
   // invocamos a la función "iniciar" después de cargado el documento
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);
```

```html
<h2 id="registrate">Registrate</h2>
<div class="container-fluid formRegistro">
    <div class="container cont-formL">
        <form class="formrow">
            <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="nombre">

            <label for="Apellido">Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" name="Apellido" id="apellido">


            <label for="cod-area">Codigo de area</label>
            <input type="number" name="cod-area" id="codArea">

            <label for="celular">Telefono celular</label>
            <input type="tel" name="celular" id="celular">

            <label for="genero">Género</label>
            <select class="form-select" name="genero" id="genero">
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-formR">
        <form class="formrow">
            <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">

            <label for="Cuil-Cuit">Cuil/Cuit</label>
            <input type="text" name="Cuil-Cuit" id="cuilCuit">

            <label for="fecha-nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
            <input type="date" name="fecha-nacimiento" id="fechaNacimiento">

            <label for="edad">Edad</label>
            <input type="number" name="edad" id="edad">

            <label for="provincia">Provincia</label>
            <select type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia">
                <option value="Seleccione">-Seleccione una provincia-</option>
                <option value="Buenos Aires">Buenos Aires</option>
                <option value="Catamarca">Catamarca</option>
                <option value="Chaco">Chaco</option>
                <option value="Chubut">Chubut</option>
            </select>

            <div class="btnForm">
                <button type="button" class="btn btnTop btn-warning" id="btnregistro">Registrarme</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btnBottom btn-warning">Borrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

PD: he puesto los `snippets`, pero parece que por problemas de seguridad? (arroja un mensaje tipo, "esta operación es insegura), no funciona, el código lo he probado en un navegador y funciona correctamente.
Espero que te sirva.